# How to get number of digits in both right, left sides of a decimal number

Tags: php, math, decimal

I wonder if is there a good way to get the number of digits in right/left side of a decimal number PHP. For example:

`12345.789`   -> RIGHT SIDE LENGTH IS **3** / LEFT SIDE LENGTH IS **5**

I know it is readily attainable by helping `string` functions and exploding the number. I mean is there a mathematically or programmatically way to perform it better than string manipulations.

Your answers would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

The best solution for left side till now was:

```
$left = floor(log10($x))+1;
```

but still no sufficient for right side.
Still waiting ...

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using string methods to accomplish this?

Comment: `ceil(log($number, 10))` to get number of digits in the integer part

Comment: You can get the left side with `ceil(log10($number)))`, _BUT_: there _is_ no right side length... it's a float, is has no defined precision.

Comment: Nothing wrong with string functions for checks - you don't need to modify the original variable

Comment: ... and `ceil(log10(strrev($number))))` for the right part ;-D

Comment: @JohnConde,@scrowler No, this is a challenging question in order to find a mathematical way. As I said in my question, I wonder if ...

Comment: @zerkms :)) Thanks. it was interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am lost on `PHP` semantics big time but I guess the following would serve your purpose without the String usage (that is at least how I would do in Java but hopefully cleaner):

Working code here: http://ideone.com/7BnsR3

**Non-string solution (only Math)**

Left side is resolved hence taking the cue from your question update:

```
$value = 12343525.34541;
$left = floor(log10($value))+1;
echo($left);

$num = floatval($value); 
$right = 0;

while($num != round($num, $right)) {
  $right++;
}

echo($right);
```

Prints

```
85
```

8 for the LHS and 5 for the RHS.

Since I'm taking a `floatval` that would make 155.0 as `0` RHS which I think is valid and can be resolved by String functions.

Answer (score 3):

To get the digits on the left side you can do this:

```
$left = floor(log10($x))+1;
```

This uses the base 10 logarithm to get the number of digits.

The right side is harder. A simple approach would look like this, but due to floating point numbers, it would often fail:

```
$decimal = $x - floor($x);
$right = 0;
while (floor($decimal) != $decimal) {
    $right++;
    $decimal *= 10; //will bring in floating point 'noise' over time
}
```

This will loop through multiplying by 10 until there are no digits past the decimal. That is tested with `floor($decimal) != $decimal`.

However, as Ali points out, giving it the number 155.11 (a hard to represent digit in binary) results in a answer of 14. This is because as the number is stored as something like 155.11000000000001 with the 32 bits of floating precision we have.

So instead, a more robust solution is needed. (PoPoFibo's solutions above is particularly elegant, and uses PHPs inherit float comparison functions well).

The fact is, we can never distinguish between input of 155.11 and 155.11000000000001. We will never know which number was originally given. They will both be represented the same. However, if we define the number of zeroes that we can see in a row before we just decide the decimal is 'done' than we can come up with a solution:

```
$x = 155.11; //the number we are testing

$LIMIT = 10; //number of zeroes in a row until we say 'enough'

$right = 0; //number of digits we've checked
$empty = 0; //number of zeroes we've seen in a row

while (floor($x) != $x) {
    $right++;

    $base = floor($x); //so we can see what the next digit is;
    $x *= 10;
    $base *= 10;

    $digit = floor($x) - $base; //the digit we are dealing with

    if ($digit == 0) {
        $empty += 1;
        if ($empty == $LIMIT) {
            $right -= $empty; //don't count all those zeroes
            break; // exit the loop, we're done
        }
    } else {
        $zeros = 0;
    }
}
```

This should find the solution given the reasonable assumption that 10 zeroes in a row means any other digits just don't matter.

However, I still like PopoFibo's solution better, as without any multiplication, PHPs default comparison functions effectively do the same thing, without the messiness.

Comment: Thanks, Great solution for left side. But while I'm testing the right side with `155.11` I get the wrong answer

Comment: @AliMasudianPour, I'm a year late, but you are correct. I've fixed the solution to be more robust.

Answer (score 1):

```
php > $num = 12345.789;
php > $left = strlen(floor($num));
php > $right = strlen($num - floor($num));
php > echo "$left / $right\n";
5 / 16   <--- 16 digits, huh?
php > $parts = explode('.', $num);
php > var_dump($parts);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "789"
```

As you can see, floats aren't the easiest to deal with... Doing it "mathematically" leads to bad results. Doing it by strings works, but makes you feel dirty.

Comment: I believe the poster was specifically asking for non-string methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = 12345.789;

list($whole, $fraction) = sscanf($number, "%d.%d");
```

This will always work, even if `$number` is an integer and you’ll get two real integers returned. Length is best done with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) even for integer values. The proposed [`log10()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log10.php) approach won't work for 10, 100, 1000, … as you might expect.

```
// 5 - 3
echo strlen($whole) , " - " , strlen($fraction);
```

If you really, really want to get the length without calling any string function here you go. But it's totally not efficient at all compared to `strlen()`.

```
/**
 * Get integer length.
 *
 * @param integer $integer
 *   The integer to count.
 * @param boolean $count_zero [optional]
 *   Whether 0 is to be counted or not, defaults to FALSE.
 * @return integer
 *   The integer's length.
 */
function get_int_length($integer, $count_zero = false) {
    // 0 would be 1 in string mode! Highly depends on use case.
    if ($count_zero === false && $integer === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return floor(log10(abs($integer))) + 1;
}

// 5 - 3
echo get_int_length($whole) , " - " , get_int_length($fraction);
```

The above will correctly count the result of `1 / 3`, but be aware that the precision is important.

```
$number = 1 / 3;
// Above code outputs
// string : 1 - 10
// math   : 0 - 10

$number = bcdiv(1, 3);
// Above code outputs
// string : 1 - 0       <-- oops
// math   : 0 - INF     <-- 8-)
```

No problem there.

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour: that's because your question is about strings. How many digits in a fraction part for the `1/3`?

Comment: Actually you aren't manipulating anything. We are counting characters of an integer value, the fact that it's internally cast to a string doesn't mean that your integer is becoming a string. It's simply the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think so :) @ Fleshgrinder Your solution was one of the best approaches that I ever seen. Another thing is that, of course I know that the final result can be easily used as Integer. But I wonder if is there a solution to perform it mathematically. something like log10(which does not give us the correct answer in some solutions)

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour: if you don't think so - please answer how many digits are in decimal representation of a `1 / 3` number.

Comment: Extended my answer to avoid string function, but it's inefficient.

Comment: @zerkms :D There are 1 digit in left side and one in right.

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour: are you sure you divided `1` by `3`? If so - how about you giving me a dollar and I will return you 3 times of 1/3 parts that was calculated by you as `0.3`?

Comment: @zerkms Oh, You mean division. What you are talking about is a mathematical issue. Of course that there are a lot of 3 in right side.  I just want to get the digit number for a pre-defined number. for example 7899.98765. Not the answer of an expression which can contain an unlimited number :)

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour: it's not a mathematical issue in any way.

Comment: @zerkms :)) we can call it anything. But what you are talking about is not our problem right now.

Comment: I extended my answer again and took `1 / 3` into account. Hope this answers all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to apply a simple logic.

```
<?php
$num=12345.789;
$num_str="".$num; // Converting number to string
$array=explode('.',$num_str); //Explode number (String) with .

echo "Left side length : ".intval(strlen($array[0])); // $array[0] contains left hand side then check the string length 
echo "<br>";
if(sizeof($array)>1)
{
echo "Left side length : ".intval(strlen($array[1]));// $array[1] contains left hand  check the string length side
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your answer. But, isn't it easier? `list($right,$left)=explode(".",(string)12345.1234);` an just: `echo strlen($right);` and `echo strlen($left);` But the question is about to resolve the problem mathematically.